# How to get .cgi files working in python with Apache on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, python

I am not really sure whether to post this here or on SO. I think this has more to do with server administration so i am posting it here. I have apache 2.2 installed on my ubuntu 10.10 system with libapache2-mod-python. However when i put a .cgi file with python in it in my apache root (/var/www) it doesn't get executed and all i see is the script i have written. For example this should show the text "Test":

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Test"
```

However the above script shows up in my browser. Any idea what conf files,etc. i'll have to go through and change to allow this to work ? (the file perms on test.cgi is 755 if that makes a difference.)

Comment: i found the answer. How do i close the question ?

Answer (score 1):

this was what i was looking for --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799354/configure-apache-to-use-python-just-like-cgi-php .